# Scanning (sscanf) large integer into bytes

Tags: c, scanf

I need to `sscanf` a 20 digit number, which is just out of range of `uint64_t`.  If I can't have the entire number in a `uint64_t`, I'd like to have it as `uint8_t[10]` (representing 2 digits per byte), which I can get doing this:

```
const char *resp = "+QCCID: 89445003071864431280";

void parse_bytes() {
  uint8_t bytes[10] = {0};
  sscanf(resp, "+QCCID: %2hhu%2hhu%2hhu%2hhu%2hhu%2hhu%2hhu%2hhu%2hhu%2hhu", 
         &bytes[9], &bytes[8], &bytes[7], &bytes[6], &bytes[5], 
         &bytes[4], &bytes[3], &bytes[2], &bytes[1], &bytes[0]);

  // print just for testing, not the end result
  for(int i=9; i>=0; i--) {
    printf("%02d", bytes[i]);
  }
}
```

This works just fine but is not particularly pretty code.  Is there a more concise way of scanning something like this into an array?

To clarify the intent for the result:  the result won't be used in a calculation, it will be sent via Bluetooth Low Energy to another device.

Update: I ended up going with a modified version of what @PetarVelev suggested.  I  used a bit field struct, for reasons outside the scope of this question.  In case anyone is interested, I posted my solution as one of the answers bellow.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with this number?  Are you performing some calculation on it?  If so, what exactly?

Comment: It's meant to go over BLE to a different device, hence the need to keep the memory footprint as small as possible.

Comment: What is the other end doing with it?  If it's just being printed as an ID it makes more sense to send it as text.  Sure, it will take up 20 bytes but then the use more closely fits the formatting as is less cumbersome and confusing.

Comment: Once it gets to the other end, it'll just be saved in a database.  I do agree treating it as string would be less cumbersome.  There is user interaction involved so I'll need to see how much extra delay is cause by 10 more bytes over BLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the question and the OP comment you need a smaller footprint and will not use the number for any operations except print.

Then, why don't you use the same technique to get the first 18 digits in the `uint64_t` and the last two in one `uint8_t`.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    char arr[21] = "01234567890123456789";
    unsigned long long int a;
    unsigned char b;

    sscanf(arr, "%18llu%2hhu",&a,&b);

    printf("%18llu%2hhu",a,b);

    return 0;
 }
```

Note that the leading zero will not be printed.

This will reduce the memory footprint by 1 byte and obviously you cannot go less than this because it doesn't fit in 8 bytes(uint64_t).

Comment: I did consider that but that makes for clunky code as well.  I now need to move around 2 variables as opposed to one.  To clarify, it's not used to print (I just included that as a minimum example).  The end result will be sent via Bluetooth Low Energy to another device.

Comment: This is just storing the information. Theoretically, it can be stored in 65 bits but this does not help you since it is sent byte by byte. So 9 is the minimum.
You can convert the information to 9 bytes which you'll send and then represent them on the other device. Consider creating a struct of `uint64_t` and `uint8_t` assuming your function expects a pointer, cast the pointer to the struct to `uint8_t*` and send 9 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Code can use a loop and `"%n"` to track scanning progress.

Might not be prettier, yet does allow for easier M changes.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 10

int parse_bytes(const char *resp) {
  uint8_t bytes[M] = {0};
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(resp, "+QCCID: %n", &n);
  if (n == 0) return -1;  // missing prefix 
  int m;
  for (m = 0; m < M; m++) { 
    resp += n;
    n = 0;
    sscanf(resp, "%2" SCNu8 "%n", &bytes[M - 1 - m], &n);
    if (n == 0) return -1;  // missing number
  } 
  if (resp[n]) return -1;  // trailing junk

  for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%02d", bytes[i]);
  }
  return m;
}
```

---

If code wanted to insure consecutive digits and no whitespace or sign characters, could add test:

```
    n = 0;
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *resp)) return -1;  // digit expected.
    sscanf(resp, "%2" SCNu8 "%n", &bytes[M - 1 - m], &n);
```

A case not handled.  OP asserted "20 digit number".  If less than that, we should re-think the whole approach.  Perhaps scan digit by digit into  `d[M*2]` and then form `bytes[]` from the "right" or maybe:

```
  int n1, n2 = 0; 
  sscanf(resp, "+QCCID: %n%*[0-9]%n", &n1, &n2);
  if (n2 == 0 || n2 - n1 > 2*M) fail();

  // now process resp[n2-1] to resp[n1] with TBD code
```

Many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is below.  I ended up with a bit field struct because it turned out that I need to use first 6 digits elsewhere.  Further, this is running on an embedded system with a `newlib nano` which doesn't support 64 bit formatting, so I can't scan/print `uint64_t`.

Of course, since you can't take an address of a bit field, I scan into `uint32_t` first and then create the struct.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
  uint32_t d1_6   : 20;
  uint32_t d7_12  : 20;
  uint32_t d13_20 : 32;
} lte_sim_iccid_t;

lte_sim_iccid_t parse_into_struct() {
  uint8_t bytes[10] = {0};

  uint32_t i1 = 0, i2 = 0, i3 = 0;
  sscanf(resp, "+QCCID: %6u%6u%8u", &i1, &i2, &i3);

  lte_sim_iccid_t s = { i1, i2, i3 };

  // sanity check
  printf("ICCID: %u %u %u (size %lu bytes)\n", s.d1_6, s.d7_12, s.d13_20, sizeof(s));
  return s;
}
```